# CSS background position 50% 50% does not work

Tags: html, css

There is an element, which width and height is not known. I would like to create a background in CSS, which is repeated, and starts at the center of the element. It should look like this:

My code is:

```
body {
    background: url('http://www.lighthouse3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/crate.jpg') 50% 50% / 100% 100% repeat;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5omLL24d/

Comment: This would be way easier if you modified the image to have the center part _in_ the center already. (Dunno if that is on option, you weren't specific about the conditions much.)

Comment: I will modify the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    background: url('http://www.lighthouse3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/crate.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DaanHai/5omLL24d/1/)

**UPDATED (corners in center, webkit)**
*Thanks, CBroe and Lovelock*

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    background: url('http://www.lighthouse3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/crate.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: -webkit-calc(50% + 128px) -webkit-calc(50% + 128px); // 128 pixels is half of the background image
    background-position: calc(50% + 128px) calc(50% + 128px); // 128 pixels is half of the background image
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DaanHai/5omLL24d/7/)

Comment: I think they want the four corners of the image to meet in the center ...

Comment: @CBroe Would also mention to use -webkit-calc as well. Always have issues with Safari unless using that for calc.

Answer (score 0):

No need to add additional css property. you will directly use this way

```
body {
    background: url('http://www.lighthouse3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/crate.jpg');
}
```

Comment: If you required you will add   background-repeat: repeat; property

Answer (score -1):

try this one:

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    background: url('http://www.lighthouse3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/crate.jpg');

    background-position: center;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/5omLL24d/3/)