# Equivalent of background-position for inline image

Tags: html, css

I can't use background image because I'm using Django variables into CSS.

I looked at these
[Image position equivalent to background position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42236938/image-position-equivalent-to-background-position) and 
[CSS background position 50% 50% does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38410282/css-background-position-50-50-does-not-work) (the suggested answer here uses `background-position`, where I just want to use an `<img>` tag).

I want to replicate this into just an `<img>` tag. everything looks good except `background-position: 50% 50%`. What's the equivalent for that?

```
.main-header {
  min-height: 40%; 
  background: url('../img/parallax11.jpeg') no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

So far this has worked:

```
.cover-img {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 30%;
  overflow: hidden;
  height:30vh;
  width: 100vw;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: What's the layout/styling objective? I'm a little unclear on that.

Comment: can you give us a demo? I plugged an image in and both of these look the same to me https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BRzyZj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent of `background-size: cover;` would be:

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

The equivalent of `background-position: 50% 50%;` would be:

```
object-position: 50% 50%;
```

See the spec on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position).

> The `object-position` property determines the alignment of the replaced
>   element inside its box.
>
> Initial value `50% 50%`

```css
.cover-inline-image,
.cover-background-image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.cover-inline-image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.cover-background-image {
  background-image: url("//unsplash.it/400/300?image=0");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
Inline image:<br>
<div class="cover-inline-image">
  <img src="//unsplash.it/400/300?image=0">
</div>

Background image:<br>
<div class="cover-background-image"></div>

How the image looks be default:<br>
<img src="//unsplash.it/400/300?image=0">
```

Answer (score 0):

`object-fit` can also 'clip' the image from coordonates via `object-position`

It would be here : `object-position: 50% 50%;` or `object-position: center center;`

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position